# Limit items in a .map loop

Tags: javascript

I would like to ask how can I limit my `.map` loop for example to a 5 items only because currently when I access an api it returns 20 items. but I want to display only 5. Mostly that I found is just looping all throughout the array of objects and not limiting it to a number of items.

Note: I have no control on the API because I'm just using the moviedb api

Here's my code:

```
var film = this.props.data.map((item) => {
  return <FilmItem key={item.id} film={item} />
});

return film;
```

Answer (score 315, accepted):

You could use [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and take only the elements you need.

```
var film = this.props.data.slice(0, 5).map((item) => {
        return <FilmItem key={item.id} film={item} />
    });

return film;
```

If you do not need the original array anymore, you could mutate the array by setting the length to `5` and iterate them.

Answer (score 20):

You could use filter() as well

```
var film = this.props.data.filter((item, idx) => idx < 5).map(item => {
   return <FilmItem key={item.id} film={item} />
});

return film;
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also limit it by passing a second argument to a `map()` callback, which would be an index of an item in the loop.

```js
const film = this.props.data?.map(
  (item, index) => 
    index < 5 && ( // <= only 5 items
      <FilmItem 
        key={item.id} 
        film={item} 
      />
    )
);

return film;
```

However, **you probably should stick to Nina's answer** unless you really need some elegancy in your code. Since I'm guessing my answer would be slower performance-wise.

**References:**

1. [MDN: map() syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#syntax)
2. [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: With your approach, you would end up with false values in the film array. I would use a filter before the map as @hozefam suggested.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi,
If you are using a functional component. you can try this:**

```
<p>const [film, setFilm] = useState([])</p>

<i>// Fetch data from API</i>

<p>useEffect(() =>{...})</p>

var fiveFilm = film.slice(0,5)
```

in your return function:

you can map using:

```
{fiveFilm.map(item => <p>{item.name}<p>)}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the way you can limit items using map function.

```js
const result = array.map((value, index) => {
        // * need only 10 items
        if (index >= 10) {
            return;
        }

        return <div key={index}>Text</div>;
    });
```