# Is it possible to iterate over the array, excluding the first element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Is it possible to iterate over the array, excluding the first element (omit the first object in the array)?

**CODE:**

```
 let multipleDemo =[];

 let people = [
    { name: 'Adam',      email: 'adam@email.com',      age: 12, 
country: 'United States' },
    { name: 'Amalie',    email: 'amalie@email.com',    age: 12, 
country: 'Argentina' },
    { name: 'Estefanía', email: 'estefania@email.com', age: 21, 
country: 'Argentina' },
    { name: 'Adrian',    email: 'adrian@email.com',    age: 21, 
country: 'Ecuador' },
    { name: 'Wladimir',  email: 'wladimir@email.com',  age: 30, 
country: 'Ecuador' },
    { name: 'Samantha',  email: 'samantha@email.com',  age: 30, 
country: 'United States' },
    { name: 'Nicole',    email: 'nicole@email.com',    age: 43, 
country: 'Colombia' },
    { name: 'Natasha',   email: 'natasha@email.com',   age: 54, 
country: 'Ecuador' },
   { name: 'Michael',   email: 'michael@email.com',   age: 15, 
country: 'Colombia' },
   { name: 'Nicolás',   email: 'nicolas@email.com',    age: 43, 
country: 'Colombia' }
  ];

for(var i =0; i < people.length; i++) {
     multipleDemo.push(people[i]);
     people.splice(people[i], 1000);
     console.log(multipleDemo);
     console.log(people);
}
```

---

Example code: https://plnkr.co/edit/UJfRUs6dAT1NC1EnOvqA?p=preview

I want to leave { name: 'Adam', email: 'adam@email.com', age: 12, country: 'United States' } in array people. Rest of elements I want to put in array multipleDemo

**I want such as FINISH EFFECT:**

```
 let multipleDemo =[,
    { name: 'Amalie',    email: 'amalie@email.com',    age: 12, 
country: 'Argentina' },
    { name: 'Estefanía', email: 'estefania@email.com', age: 21, 
country: 'Argentina' },
    { name: 'Adrian',    email: 'adrian@email.com',    age: 21, 
country: 'Ecuador' },
    { name: 'Wladimir',  email: 'wladimir@email.com',  age: 30, 
country: 'Ecuador' },
    { name: 'Samantha',  email: 'samantha@email.com',  age: 30, 
country: 'United States' },
    { name: 'Nicole',    email: 'nicole@email.com',    age: 43, 
country: 'Colombia' },
    { name: 'Natasha',   email: 'natasha@email.com',   age: 54, 
country: 'Ecuador' },
   { name: 'Michael',   email: 'michael@email.com',   age: 15, 
country: 'Colombia' },
   { name: 'Nicolás',   email: 'nicolas@email.com',    age: 43, 
country: 'Colombia' }];

 let people = [
    { name: 'Adam',      email: 'adam@email.com',      age: 12, 
country: 'United States' }
  ];
```

Comment: Why not start with `for(var i =1; i < people.length; i++) {` in your loop?

Comment: you could slice the array, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42374873/1447675

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: I want to leave    { name: 'Adam',      email: 'adam@email.com',      age: 12, 
country: 'United States' } in array people. Rest of elements I want to put in array multipleDemo

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this. but the easiest and concise solution would be using the `filter()`. Which returns an array that contains each element where the condition is met.

```js
 let people = [
    { name: 'Adam',      email: 'adam@email.com',      age: 12, 
country: 'United States' },
    { name: 'Amalie',    email: 'amalie@email.com',    age: 12, 
country: 'Argentina' },
    { name: 'Estefanía', email: 'estefania@email.com', age: 21, 
country: 'Argentina' },
    { name: 'Adrian',    email: 'adrian@email.com',    age: 21, 
country: 'Ecuador' },
    { name: 'Wladimir',  email: 'wladimir@email.com',  age: 30, 
country: 'Ecuador' },
    { name: 'Samantha',  email: 'samantha@email.com',  age: 30, 
country: 'United States' },
    { name: 'Nicole',    email: 'nicole@email.com',    age: 43, 
country: 'Colombia' },
    { name: 'Natasha',   email: 'natasha@email.com',   age: 54, 
country: 'Ecuador' },
   { name: 'Michael',   email: 'michael@email.com',   age: 15, 
country: 'Colombia' },
   { name: 'Nicolás',   email: 'nicolas@email.com',    age: 43, 
country: 'Colombia' }
  ];

let multipleDemo = people.filter((v, k) => k !== 0);
people = people.filter((v, k) => k === 0);

console.log(multipleDemo)
console.log(people)
```

Comment: I want to leave  only { name: 'Adam',      email: 'adam@email.com',      age: 12, 
country: 'United States' } in people array

Comment: the new array that is been created called `multipleDemo` doesn't have `{ name: 'Adam', email: 'adam@email.com', age: 12, country: 'United States' }`. I think this is what you wanted. Check the `multipleDemo` again

Comment: people array must to have only one element { name: 'Adam', email: 'adam@email.com', age: 12, country: 'United States' }

Comment: okay!. So you only want `{ name: 'Adam', email: 'adam@email.com', age: 12, country: 'United States' }` to be in the array. rest of the elements you don't want. right?

Comment: Updated my question. Rest of the elements put in multipleDemo array

Comment: okay!. I updated my answer. you only have 1st element left in the `people` people and rest of the elements has been moved to `multipleDemo` array

Comment: I think This is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to modify your arrays to get your desired output.

```js
let people = [{
    name: 'Adam',
    email: 'adam@email.com',
    age: 12,
    country: 'United States'
  },
  {
    name: 'Amalie',
    email: 'amalie@email.com',
    age: 12,
    country: 'Argentina'
  },
  {
    name: 'Estefanía',
    email: 'estefania@email.com',
    age: 21,
    country: 'Argentina'
  },
  {
    name: 'Adrian',
    email: 'adrian@email.com',
    age: 21,
    country: 'Ecuador'
  },
  {
    name: 'Wladimir',
    email: 'wladimir@email.com',
    age: 30,
    country: 'Ecuador'
  },
  {
    name: 'Samantha',
    email: 'samantha@email.com',
    age: 30,
    country: 'United States'
  },
  {
    name: 'Nicole',
    email: 'nicole@email.com',
    age: 43,
    country: 'Colombia'
  },
  {
    name: 'Natasha',
    email: 'natasha@email.com',
    age: 54,
    country: 'Ecuador'
  },
  {
    name: 'Michael',
    email: 'michael@email.com',
    age: 15,
    country: 'Colombia'
  },
  {
    name: 'Nicolás',
    email: 'nicolas@email.com',
    age: 43,
    country: 'Colombia'
  }
];

let multipleDemo = people.slice(1); 
people = people.slice(0, 1);
console.log(multipleDemo);
console.log('--------------------');
console.log(people);
```

Comment: I want to leave { name: 'Adam', email: 'adam@email.com', age: 12, country: 'United States' } in array people. Rest of elements I want to put in array multipleDemo

Comment: @Mario Should meet your requirements now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to unpack and assign remaining part of the array to a variable using rest pattern and use [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over them as follows:

```js
const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

const [first, ...rest] = arr;

rest.forEach(v => console.log(v));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to omit *n* elements from the beginning.

`Array.slice(1)` means you take the array starting from index `1` to the end.

You can also define until which element you want to slice off.

`Array.slice(1, 3)` will slice the elements of index `1` and `2`. It will be Amalie and Estefanía in this case.

```js
let people = [
  { name: "Adam", email: "adam@email.com", age: 12, country: "United States" },
  { name: "Amalie", email: "amalie@email.com", age: 12, country: "Argentina" },
  { name: "Estefanía", email: "estefania@email.com", age: 21, country: "Argentina" },
  { name: "Adrian", email: "adrian@email.com", age: 21, country: "Ecuador" },
  { name: "Wladimir", email: "wladimir@email.com", age: 30, country: "Ecuador" },
  { name: "Samantha", email: "samantha@email.com", age: 30, country: "United States" },
  { name: "Nicole", email: "nicole@email.com", age: 43, country: "Colombia" },
  { name: "Natasha", email: "natasha@email.com", age: 54, country: "Ecuador" },
  { name: "Michael", email: "michael@email.com", age: 15, country: "Colombia" },
  { name: "Nicolás", email: "nicolas@email.com", age: 43, country: "Colombia" }
];

let multipleDemo = people.slice(1);

multipleDemo.forEach(function (current) {
  console.log(current.name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you simply want to copy the elements from `people` array to `multipleDemo`  array excluding the first element, you could use slice() array method.

```
multipleDemo = people.slice(1)
```

`.slice(1)` will copy the contents of `people` array from index1 without reference to the `multipleDemo` array.
[.slice() in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)