# What to do if i want to show the first 5 elements from the array by using forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach

There are 10 elements in an array.  What to do if i want to show the first 5 elements from the array by using forEach loop?

```
let arrays =[1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 44, 5, 7, 6]
 arrays.forEach(array =>{}) //
```

Comment: have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374873/limit-items-in-a-map-loop/42374933#42374933

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883068/how-to-get-first-n-number-of-elements-from-an-array

Answer (score 3):

To show the first 5 elements from the array by using forEach loop, you can use if statement

```
const arrays = [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 44, 5, 7, 6];

arrays.forEach(function(value, index, array) {

    if(index <= 4) {
        document.write(value + "<br>");
    }

});
```

Where parameters:

- Index = The index of the current element.
- Value = The value of the current element.
- Array = The array of the current element.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp